# jquery plug in or Html Code

Tags: jquery-plugins, photos

Is there a way to add additional photos per set? I can’t see the previous and next buttons once i click on one single image from the gallery images. Does anyone know the code i need to activate this? The gallery was built using Pretty Photo lightbox plugin. I appreciate your time in advance. thanks

example of site: http://www.diligentworks.com/FOA/index1.htm

this actually reads like this:

### PHOTO GALLERY

```
        <div class="tabcontent"> 
          <div class="gallery"> <a href="./img/p1/foa01.jpg" rel="gallery" title="gallery-item-01"><img src="./img/tgallery-item-01.jpg" width="150" height="120" alt="gallery-item-01" /></a> 
            <a href="./img/gallery-item-02.jpg" rel="gallery" title="gallery-item-02"><img src="./img/tgallery-item-02.jpg" width="150" height="120" alt="gallery-item-01" /></a> 
            <a href="./img/gallery-item-03.jpg" rel="gallery" title="gallery-item-03"><img src="./img/tgallery-item-03.jpg" width="150" height="120" alt="gallery-item-01" /></a> 
            <a href="./img/gallery-item-04.jpg" rel="gallery" title="gallery-item-04"><img src="./img/tgallery-item-04.jpg" width="150" height="120" alt="gallery-item-01" /></a> 
            <a href="./img/gallery-item-05.jpg" rel="gallery" title="gallery-item-05"><img src="./img/tgallery-item-05.jpg" width="150" height="120" alt="gallery-item-01" /></a> 
            <a href="./img/gallery-item-06.jpg" rel="gallery" title="gallery-item-06"><img src="./img/tgallery-item-06.jpg" width="150" height="120" alt="gallery-item-01" /></a>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://forums.no-margin-for-errors.com/discussion/comment/2958/#Comment_2958:

> To use the gallery functionality, you
>   need to add the gallery name in
>   braket. Like so:
>
> `<a href="" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]">`